# Python Prg - Python programming test

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me write a Python code.

**Programming Test:**
a river has n number of stones that a person can walk across to get to the other side!

Write a function that prints the total number possibilities of crossing the river where the person has the option of 1 or 2 stones per step. Include all possible combinations

**For example** 
If n = 1 Therefore the result should print 1 (1)
If n = 4 Therefore the result should print 5 (1,1,1,1) (2,2) (2,1,1) (1,2,1) (1,1,2)

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score -1):

If you have to walk n steps, you can walk all n-1 steps with one stone more or all n-2 with additionally 2 stones. So its a simple Fibonacci.

```
def river(n):
    if (n == 0): return (0)
    if (n == 1): return (1)
    if (n == 2): return (2)
       return(river(n-1)+river(n-2))
```